# How to speed up calculation of polygon area?

Tags: netlogo

The following code allows to calculate area (ha) of white polygons in a large landscape (900 x 900 patches). But this code is too slow. Is there a way to speed up calculation ?

```
 let list-ID-blocks ( [ID-polygon] of patches with [pcolor = white] )
 foreach list-ID-blocks [ 
 ask patches with [ID-polygon = ?] [ 
 set polygon-area ( count patches with [ID-polygon = ?] ) * 0.01 ] ]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that every single patch is calculating the area independently (`count patches with [ ID-polygon = ? ]` loops through every single patch every time you call it). Instead you can calculate the area for each polygon once, like so:

```
let list-ID-blocks remove-duplicates [ID-polygon] of patches with [pcolor = white]
foreach list-ID-blocks [
  let area 0.01 * count patches with [ ID-polygon = ? ]
  ask ask patches with [ ID-polygon = ? ] [ set polygon-area area ]
]
```

That should be much faster. If it is fast enough, I'd go with that. However, it's still looking at every patch once for each polygon. If polygon ids are just integers between 0 and some number, you can look at each patch once, counting up the areas:

```
let max-id max [ ID-polygon ] of patches with [ pcolor = white ]
let areas n-values max-id [ 0 ]
ask patches with [ pcolor = white ] [
  let old-area item ID-polygon areas
  set areas replace-item ID-polygon areas (old-area + 1)
]
ask patches with [ pcolor = white ] [
  set polygon-area 0.01 * item polygon-ID areas
]
```